# Some Custom logs are not showing in Fabrics Crashlytics

Tags: android, logging, crashlytics-android

I know this question is asked several times but nowhere, I have not find any suitable answer. Some Custom logs just before crashing is not showing in Fabrics Crashlytics. Is there any straight  way to get all logs.I don't want to use that UncaughtExceptionHandler. Is there any other way?

Comment: Similar to the original question, if you write logs using Crashlytics and in the next line throw a new RuntimeException, then those logs too are not displayed in the dashboard.